# StoryBook: how to test modal views?

Tags: react-native, modal-dialog, storybook

I use [StoryBook](https://storybook.js.org) to develop the views of my [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native) mobile application. This works OK for "regular" views, but when I display a *modal* view (implemented using [`react-native-modal`](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal)), I get "locked in", i.e. the StoryBook UI used to switch between views under development is inaccessible (due to the modal view being "too modal").

I can somewhat work around this by e.g. adding a button to the modal view under development to close it in order to make the storybook UI accessible again, but obviously, I would like to see the "production" contents only, i.e. the modal view without any "helper UI".

Is there any way to e.g. close the modal view using built-in StoryBook functionality or [Addons](https://storybook.js.org/addons), e.g. [Knobs](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/tree/master/addons/knobs) ?

How would I generally go about developing / displaying modal views in StoryBook ?

Comment: The only solution I found so far is to have the 'helper UI' you mentioned and use a [story state](https://gist.github.com/colinfwren/af22dfe0ecd52e3655009fef6158c7b7) to toggle modal on / off. Did anyone find a solution to this 2 y old question? Like @ssc I am looking for something like the [web version](https://cdn.wfp.org/guides/ui/v1.3.1/docs/?path=/story/components-modal--default) contained modal inside the story preview not toggled.

Comment: having same problem after 4 years. im on "@storybook/react": "^6.5.14"

Answer (score -3):

your question is unclear like when do you exactly use modal to display something. but what i can understand is the modal once opens doesnt close. so react-native-modal offers some inbuilt props like :
`**onBackButtonPress**  func    () => null  Called when the Android back button is pressed
**onBackdropPress** func    () => null  Called when the backdrop is pressed`
[react-native-modal docs](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal)

So what ive used in my personal experience is maintaining a state which acts as flag when to display the modal. For eg in constructor initialize a state like `isVisibleModal:false`.
And when you want to render the modal , change the state to `isVisibleModal:true`. and when the modal opens,react-native-modal props like `onBackdropPress and onBackButtonPress` will come in handy where you can again change the state to `isVisibleModal:false` and your modal will hide and your storybook will be rendered. In the render func all you need to do is add below code for modal

`render(){
return(
{this.state.isVisibleModal?<ModalComponent/>:<View></View>}
)
}`

Comment: I think you should play with Storybook and Modals for a bit. Storybook allows you to see a list of your components in a navigator and a preview of each story(component with some mocked state/params) you describe. This helps developers in your team to see what components are already implemented and how do they look. The React Native problem described is if you click on the story that contains the modal it goes over the storybook wrapper app itself and you can't click other components and have to refresh the app if you want to continue exploring. Sadly, modal is not captured inside the preview.